# web api with angular errors

Tags: c#, angular, asp.net-web-api, web

```js
import { browser, element, by } from 'protractor';

describe('QuickStart E2E Tests', function () {

  let expectedMsg = 'Hello Angular';

  beforeEach(function () {
    browser.get('');
  });

  it('should display: ' + expectedMsg, function () {
    expect(element(by.css('h1')).getText()).toEqual(expectedMsg);
  });

});
```

```js
import { Operator } from './Operator';
import { Observer } from './Observer';
import { Observable } from './Observable';
import { Subscriber } from './Subscriber';
import { ISubscription, Subscription } from './Subscription';
/**
 * @class SubjectSubscriber<T>
 */
export declare class SubjectSubscriber<T> extends Subscriber<T> {
    protected destination: Subject<T>;
    constructor(destination: Subject<T>);
}
/**
 * @class Subject<T>
 */
export declare class Subject<T> extends Observable<T> implements ISubscription {
    observers: Observer<T>[];
    closed: boolean;
    isStopped: boolean;
    hasError: boolean;
    thrownError: any;
    constructor();
    static create: Function;
    lift<R>(operator: Operator<T, R>): Observable<T>;
    next(value?: T): void;
    error(err: any): void;
    complete(): void;
    unsubscribe(): void;
    protected _subscribe(subscriber: Subscriber<T>): Subscription;
    asObservable(): Observable<T>;
}
/**
 * @class AnonymousSubject<T>
 */
export declare class AnonymousSubject<T> extends Subject<T> {
    protected destination: Observer<T>;
    constructor(destination?: Observer<T>, source?: Observable<T>);
    next(value: T): void;
    error(err: any): void;
    complete(): void;
    protected _subscribe(subscriber: Subscriber<T>): Subscription;
}
```

I have just opened a new web api project using Angular. This is the first time I've been using Angular. I worked according to this guide: https://angular.io/guide/visual-studio-2015
But I get errors. Does anyone know how to solve this?
Thanks!

**erroe 1 :**

> Severity   Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
>   Error   TS2416  (TS) Property 'lift' in type 'Subject' is not assignable to the same property in base type 'Observable'.
>     Type '(operator: Operator) => Observable' is not assignable to type '(operator: Operator) => Observable'.
>       Type 'Observable' is not assignable to type 'Observable'.
>         Type 'T' is not assignable to type 'R'.   C:\Users\איתי\source\repos\Ctaxi - WeWorkShop\Ctaxi - WeWorkShop\src (tsconfig or jsconfig project) C:\Users\איתי\source\repos\Ctaxi - WeWorkShop\Ctaxi - WeWorkShop\node_modules\rxjs\Subject.d.ts 24  Active

**error 2:**

> Severity   Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
>   Error   TS2559  (TS) Type 'By' has no properties in common with type 'Locator'. C:\Users\איתי\source\repos\Ctaxi - WeWorkShop\Ctaxi - WeWorkShop\e2e (tsconfig or jsconfig project) C:\Users\איתי\source\repos\Ctaxi - WeWorkShop\Ctaxi - WeWorkShop\e2e\app.e2e-spec.ts    12  Active

Comment: It would help if you showed your code that is throwing the errors.

Comment: @Ron Beyer i cant uplode pic can i send it to you?

Comment: Code is text, please [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/51973977/edit) and add the code in there. Pictures of code don't help so much because we can't copy/paste and some images won't show up on some peoples computers.

Comment: @Ron Beyer  been done

Comment: Hey @itaytal.  Can you tell us which version of TypeScript and RxJS you are using (check your `package.json` file)?  It looks like others have may experienced this in the past. https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/17800

Comment: @nickflynn it was 3.0. i change it to 2.4 and its working

Comment: Cool.  Glad it's working then.

Answer (score 0):

for error 2:
need to do casting for "by.css('h1'))" and import locator

```js
import { browser, element, by } from 'protractor';
import { By } from 'selenium-webdriver';
import { Locator } from 'protractor/built/locators';

describe('QuickStart E2E Tests', function () {

  let expectedMsg = 'Hello Angular';

  beforeEach(function () {
    browser.get('');
  });

  it('should display: ' + expectedMsg, function () {
    expect(element(<Locator>by.css('h1')).getText()).toEqual(expectedMsg);
  });

});
```